# I am trying to capture the output of the bash command

Tags: bash

I am trying to capture the output of the bash command `PYVER="$(python --version)"` within the variable PYVER. For some reason it doesn't seem to work as when I check using `echo "$PYVER"` it returns nothing (blank line). Through my leaning of bash scripts (I am new to this) I have tried capturing other outputs in this format and it has worked. If anyone can find my error I would be greatly appreciative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since python writes the version to stderr this should work:

```
PYVER=$(python --version 2>&1)
echo $PYVER
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem I think is that python --version sends it's output to stder, not stdout.
The redirects below seem to do what you want.

```
$PYVER="$(python --version 2>&1 > /dev/null)"
$echo $PYVER
$Python 2.7.10
```